# Galois group of a polynomial of degree 5

Tags: galois-theory, finite-fields

I have a symmetric polynomial $p(x) = x^5+a_4(y)x^4 + a_3(y)x^3+a_2(y)x^2+a_1(y)x+a_0(y)$ over the ring $F_q[x,y]$ where $F_q$ is a finite field with $q$ elements.

With experiment, i know that in case $q=9 \pmod {10}$, for each $y \in F_q$, $p(x)$ has one root. Therefore for each $y \in F_q$, $p(x)$ is not irreducible in this case, I try to use the Galois's theory to proof that $p(x)$ has one root and this means that Galois group of $p(x)$ is $Id ‎\times S_4$, Is this true?

My information on Galois's theory in the finite fields is limited, Please help me or introduce references that help me.

Thank you.

Comment: One root? In which field? Presumably in $\Bbb{F}_q(y)$?

Comment: Anyway, there is no reason why you would get $S_4$ as the Galois group. Consider the polynomial
$$p(x)=(x+y)^5-1\in\Bbb{F}_2(y)[x].$$
It has a single zero $x=y+1$ in the field $\Bbb{F}_2(y)$. The other zeros are of the form $x=y+\omega$, where $\omega$ is a primitive fifth root of unity, so an element of $\Bbb{F}_{16}$. The splitting field of $p(x)$ is $\Bbb{F}_{16}(y)$. This is a constant field extension of $\Bbb{F}_2(y)$, and the Galois group is cyclic of order four.

Comment: I see that you want the characteristic to be congruent to $1\pmod{10}$. Let's do the following. Let $q(T)$ be an irreducible quartic polynomial in $\Bbb{F}_p[T]$. Let's use
$$p(x,y)=(x+y-1)q(x+y)$$ as the symmetric polynomial. It has a single zero $x=1-y$ in $\Bbb{F}_p(y)$. The other zeros are $x=\alpha_j-y$, where $\alpha_j\in\Bbb{F}_{p^4}, j=1,2,3,4$ are the zeros of $q(T)$. Again, we have a constant field extension with Galois group cyclic of order four.

Comment: Bigger Galois groups are, of course possible with more complicated polynomials. I simply wanted to give you small examples, for it is not quite clear to me what is the problem you really want to solve.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen: The problem i want to solve is compute the Galois group of $p(x)$ when it is no known that $p(x)$ is irreducible in $F_q[x,y]$, I read the book "Galois_Theory" from "David A. Cox", but in this book compute the Galois group of irreducible polynomials. I need a references that discuss and compute the Galois group of reducible polynomials in finite fields.

Comment: It seems to me that you want to compute Galois groups over $\Bbb{F}_q(y)$, an infinite field. The Galois theory of extensions of finite fields (the polynomial must then have a single variable) is simple - they are all cyclic. Can you give an example of a specific polynomial?

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen: I have a polynomial $p(u,v) \in F_q[u,v]$ which is symmetric. In case $q \equiv -1 \pmod {10}$, by experiment, I understood that $p(u,v)$ is irreducible. But for every $u \in F_q$, $p_u(v)$ is product of a linear and two quadratic polynomials.Now I want to proof this. Can you introduce references that help me?

Comment: In addition $p(u,v)= (u^3 + 1/2*(-5*t + 11)*u^2)*v^5 + (1/2*(t + 1)*u^4 + 1/2*(3*t + 29)*u^3 + 1/2*(-89*t + 197)*u^2 + (4*t - 9)*u)*v^4 + (u^5 + 1/2*(3*t + 29)*u^4 +
        1/2*(-t + 151)*u^3 + (-186*t + 409)*u^2 + 1/2*(89*t - 197)*u + 1/2*(-5*t + 11))*v^3 + (1/2*(-5*t + 11)*u^5 + 1/2*(-89*t + 197)*u^4 + (-186*t +
        409)*u^3 + 1/2*(t - 151)*u^2 + 1/2*(3*t + 29)*u - 1)*v^2 + ((4*t - 9)*u^4 + 1/2*(89*t - 197)*u^3 + 1/2*(3*t + 29)*u^2 + 1/2*(-t - 1)*u)*v +
        1/2*(-5*t + 11)*u^3 - u^2$ where $t$ is sqrt of $5$ in $F_q$.